# How do I set a new xml layout while using tabs

Tags: android, xml, tabactivity

I am trying to create a tabbed interface which has multiple activities. As part of the tabs I have created and set an xml tabhost file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

This is called in my Tabs.class file which looks like this:

```java
package com.system.kenetix;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class Tabs extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Availability.class);
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Availability").setIndicator("Booking",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.kenetix_tab_available))
            .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, RoomsAvailable.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Room").setIndicator("Rooms",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.kinetix_tab_rooms))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CustomerDetails.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Customer").setIndicator("Customer",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.kinetix_tab_customer))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Payment.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Payment").setIndicator("Payment",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.kinetix_tab_payment))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Extras.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Extras").setIndicator("Extras",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.kinetix_tab_extras))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

I then have individual classes for each of my tabs and an xml file to set the content (Buttons, spinners etc) like so:

```java
package com.system.kenetix;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Availability extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Intent intent = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.availability);

    /*Nights Spinner*/

    //Create an instance of the Number of Nights spinner
    Spinner NumNightsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.NumAdultsSpinner);

    //Create an ArrayAdapter for the Number of Nights spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.NumNights_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //Set the adapter layout
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //Apply the adapter layout to the Number of Nights spinner
    NumNightsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    NumNightsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnNumNightsSelectedListener());

    /*Adults Spinner*/

    //Create an instance of the Number of Adults spinner
    Spinner NumAdultsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.NumAdultsSpinner);

    //Create an ArrayAdapter for the Number of adults spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.NumAdults_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //Set the adapter layout
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //Apply the adapter layout to the Number of Adults spinner
    NumAdultsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    NumAdultsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnNumAdultsSelectedListener());

    /*Children Spinner*/

    //Create an instance of the Number of Children spinner
    Spinner NumChildSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.NumChildSpinner);

    //Create an ArrayAdapter for the Number of Children spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.NumChild_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //Set the adapter layout
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //Apply the adapter layout to the Number of Children spinner
    NumChildSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    NumChildSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnNumChildSelectedListener());

    Button CheckAvailable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CheckAvailabilityBtn);
    CheckAvailable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RoomsAvailable.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

//Listener for the selected item from the number of nights spinner
public class MyOnNumNightsSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id){

        //If no number of nights has been selected or onCreate occurs cancel the toast
        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("0")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " night(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).cancel();
        }

        //Else create a toast stating the number of nights selected
        else{
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " night(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
//Listener for the selected item from the number of adults spinner
public class MyOnNumAdultsSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id){

        //If no number of nights has been selected or onCreate occurs cancel the toast
        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("0")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " adults", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).cancel();
        }

        else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("1")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " adult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).cancel();
        }

        //Else create a toast stating the number of nights selected
        else{
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " adult(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Do Nothing
    }
}
//Listener for the selected item from the number of adults spinner
public class MyOnNumChildSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id){

        //If no number of nights has been selected or onCreate occurs cancel the toast
        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("0")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " children", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).cancel();
        }
        else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("1")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " child", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Else create a toast stating the number of nights selected
        else{
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " children", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Do Nothing
    }
}

}
```

and the xml that goes with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:background="@color/custom_theme_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/QuickRoomSelect" android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/QuickCustomerDetails" android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_theme_text_color" android:id="@+id/availabilityLbl"
        android:text="@string/AvailableLbl" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/DateFromBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="@string/DateFromBtn"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView android:textColor="@color/custom_theme_text_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/NumNightsLdl"
        android:text="@string/NumNightsLbl" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/NumAdultsSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:textColor="@color/custom_theme_text_color"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/NumAdultsLbl"
                android:text="@string/NumAdultsLbl" android:layout_weight="2"></TextView>
            <TextView android:textColor="@color/custom_theme_text_color"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/NumChildLbl"
                android:layout_weight="2" android:text="@string/NumChildLbl"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/NumNightsSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>
            <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/NumChildSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/CheckAvailabilityBtn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/CheckAvailableBtn"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*Basically what I need to know is how do I get the `Availability.class` file to use the second xml file?* All that I can see is the tabs which looks great! *I don't want to have to create the buttons etc. in the main code as I'm trying to be as OO as possible.* All of the examples I have seen either use the tabs.xml to layout the activity which is great if you want every tab to have the same information, or the layout stuff is written straight into the java class.

Is it possible to do what I want? If so can someone advise me in how to do this or link me to somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is basically exactly how  my application is organized (with a second version I am fiddling around with that is View-based instead).

There seems to be a bit of an issue with your Tabs XML file though.

1) Why do you have the xmlns:android tag twice? TabHost and LinearLayout both have it - remove the one from the LinearLayout.

2) Not sure about the match_parent layout params on the LinearLayout (this is likely not the issue though) - my first TabHost (later revised a bit) looked like this, which is very similar to yours (I imagine we followed the same tutorial off the Android docs ;)), and worked just fine:

```
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Try to fix the first thing and it should work just fine, I see no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that mistake out, I have tried it but still no success. The tab.xml seems fine as I'm able to view the tabs, its the content within the activities that isn't showing. I'm using another xml file to hold this information.

Sorry I'm not very technical in my explanations :(

Comment: Really? Damn, I'm not sure then. My code is honestly exactly the same way. Hey, did you add the 2nd Activity to the Manifest?

Comment: Yes I've added it, I don't have to do anything fancy with it do I? I've got <activity android:name="Availability"/>

Comment: @alsobubbly: Oh man, I hope that's just a typo. Your entire problem may be down to you missing a period. It's supposed to be .Availability - all Activies have a . in front of them in the Manifest. ie: `<activity android:name=".BalanceActivity"></activity>`

Comment: Oh right I just used the application generator thing in eclipse and that's want it did. So add the . and it might work then? I'll give it a go. :) Thank you

Comment: No that didn't make any difference. I'm completely stuck now. Is there any chance you could let me have a sample of your code so I can cross check it, that way I'll be able to see if I've made a noobie mistake. :)